# Then Vs Await issue

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

You dont have to read the code, what is happening is a file is being uploaded 1000 bytes at a time. And to ensure that we send the bytes in order we are using `await`. What if I wanted to use `.then()`, it seems hard as there is a loop around the fetch call.

```
        const fileReader = new FileReader();
        const theFile = f.files[0];
        fileReader.onload = async (ev) => {
          const CHUNK_SIZE = 5000;
          const chunkCount = ev.target.result.byteLength / CHUNK_SIZE;

          console.log("Read successfully");
          const fileName = Math.random() * 1000 + theFile.name;
          for (let chunkId = 0; chunkId < chunkCount + 1; chunkId++) {
            const chunk = ev.target.result.slice(
              chunkId * CHUNK_SIZE,
              chunkId * CHUNK_SIZE + CHUNK_SIZE
            );
            await fetch("http://localhost:8080/upload", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
                "content-length": chunk.length,
                "file-name": fileName,
              },
              body: chunk,
            });
            divOutput.textContent =
              Math.round((chunkId * 100) / chunkCount, 0) + "%";
          }
          console.log(ev.target.result.byteLength);
        };
        fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(theFile);
      });
```

Comment: you'd need a recusion

Comment: thats what i thought too, thank you

Comment: send the chunk number along with it or as part of filename then you can send in any order, serverside you would have filename.ext.part1, filename.ext.part2 etc etc, then you order the chunks and concatenate them, something like `cat tmp_upload/filename.ext.part* > uploads/filename.ext`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the same functionality without `await`. It replaces the `for` loop:

```
const uploadChunk = (chunkId = 0) => {
  const chunk = ev.target.result.slice(
    chunkId * CHUNK_SIZE,
    chunkId * CHUNK_SIZE + CHUNK_SIZE
  );
  fetch("http://localhost:8080/upload", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
      "content-length": chunk.length,
      "file-name": fileName,
    },
    body: chunk,
  }).then(() => {
    divOutput.textContent =
      Math.round((chunkId * 100) / chunkCount, 0) + "%";
    (chunkId <= chunkCount) && uploadChunk(chunkId + 1);
  });
}

uploadChunk();
```

Comment: perfect answer, thanks